# Integrate $(1-\sqrt{x})/(1+\sqrt{x})$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Integrate $(1-\sqrt{x})/(1+\sqrt{x})$.

So, this was on my test, and I got

$$4(1+\sqrt{x})-4\ln(1+\sqrt{x})-x+c$$

as a result using symbolab. But my teacher gave the result shown below (his solution is [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkDhS.jpg), and transcribed below).

$$\int \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}} \, dx \;=\; 6\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)-\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)^2-2\ln\big|1-\sqrt{x}\big|+c.$$

I'm trying to understand what is wrong in symbolab or in his result, but I really can't find out.

> Teacher's solution:
>
> Let $u = 1+\sqrt{x}$. Then $1-\sqrt{x} = 2-u$, and $dx = 2(u-1)du$. Then
> \begin{align*}
> \int \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}} \, dx 
> &= \int \frac{(2-u)2(u-1)}{u} \, du
> = 2 \int \frac{3u-u^2-2}{u} \, du
> \\&= \int 6 \, du - 2 \int u \, du - 2 \int \frac{1}{u} \, du
> \\&= 6u - u^2 - 2\ln|u| + C
> \\&= 6(1-\sqrt{x}) - (1-\sqrt{x})^2 - 2\ln|1-\sqrt{x}| + C
> \end{align*}

Comment: What is unclear ?

Comment: @Surb The teacher's answer and the symbolab answer do not match up

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1-Sqrt%5Bx%5D%2C1%2BSqrt%5Bx%5D%5D%2Cx%5D). The constant isn't important. Btw, $u=1\color{red}+\sqrt x$.

Comment: @Spring, okay, so this confirms symbolab's answer. The asker then wants to know what went wrong in the teacher's solution

Comment: Have you expanded your teacher's solution? And your teacher forgot to multiply once again by $2$.

Comment: As an aside, the simbolab expression can be simplified to$$4\sqrt{x}-4\ln(1+\sqrt{x})-x+c$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your teacher made 2 separate mistakes. First when splitting the integrals:
$$2\int\frac{3u-u^2-2}{u}du=\int6\,du-2\int u \,du-4\int \frac1udu$$
They wrote a 2 instead of 4 in the final term. Then when resubstituting the expression for $u$ they used $1-\sqrt{x}$ instead of $1+\sqrt{x}$:
$$6(1+\sqrt{x})-(1+\sqrt{x})^{2}-4\ln\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)+c$$
Indeed, this is equivalent to $4(1+\sqrt{x})-4\ln(1+\sqrt{x})-x+K$ as:
$$6(1+\sqrt{x})-(1+\sqrt{x})^{2}-4\ln\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)+c=
6+6\sqrt{x}-1-2\sqrt{x}-x-4\ln\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)+c$$
$$=5+4\sqrt{x}-x-4\ln\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)+c=4(1+\sqrt{x}-\ln\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right))-x+1+c$$
And finally, let $K=1+c$.